# Symbols wont load for my project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, breakpoints, debug-symbols

I have a project I was handed that I unzipped, put on my computer, and now I can't put any breakpoints in. Whenever I try to put a breakpoint in I get an exclamation point over the breakpoint saying "This breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." Anyone know how I can fix this? This error doesn't show up until the I start to run the code, while the code isn't running the breakpoint looks like it is there just fine.

Comment: what type of project is it? ASP .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess that you might be running a release build? Check the project settings to make sure it's a debug build, otherwise breakpoints can be ignored due to compiler settings sometimes since the optimizations can make the debugger a bit upset.

Might also be worth doing a clean and rebuild all to make sure that you're running against the correct version of the binaries etc.

Comment: Even in release mode, breakpoints can be hit.  You will not be able to edit and continue though...

Comment: @Brosto: Yes, but sometimes things can get a bit funny if you debug in release mode. My post wasn't clear that that was what I meant though, so  thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware that having it set to release would cause the breakpoints not to load.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you can try:

Open up the properties page of the project(s) and select the "Build" tab. Click on "Advanced". Make sure where it says "Debug Info" that "Full" is chosen.

Additionally, delete any PDB files in the output folder.